# OpenPGP encryption in pure PHP

Tags: php, encryption, rsa, openpgp

I would like on your website, create a form that sends me a message encrypted in accordance with the OpenPGP standard in order to decrypt them by Thunderbird & Enigmail. Will include an order from an online shop. I can not use GnuPG, because my server does not support it. I found OpenPGP implementation in pure PHP is available on https://github.com/bendiken/openpgp-php/tree/master/lib and http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/. I succeeded only encrypt RSA keys, but I can not decrypted the Thunderbird.

How using or not the above software to encrypt messages in pure PHP as OpenPGP standard?

Example PGP key pair (I know what I'm doing publishing - created specifically for the publication):

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.17 (MingW32)
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=ioL3
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.17 (MingW32)
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=xK/H
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Example RSA key pair (other that PGP key pair):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGGAoGAfHlcdrcuOK6C02rbGR3SgV/ZJ2wnTiFBguh5FHduoB6LcZz49LIC/KcIiH/TckK8GxQd
oJ7wHCPBpNiumrlC6caj/C8jO/HZ3cb12Wuk4gUuJq1lg5+HTv4KRJ9pFeEFQqS6X+BTztY+EoRx
uc8MlLXS4PUeouwd9Ios2K0Y5/sCASU=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the tool you have chosen is very immature:

```
class OpenPGP_EncryptedDataPacket extends OpenPGP_Packet {
  // TODO
}
```

Installing GnuPG or GPGME would probably be far easier than trying to get a PHP implementation working, debugged, and keep it secure as problems are found and fixed in the "real" GnuPG implementation.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it is not possible for me to install GnuPG, so I have to fight with the implementation in pure PHP. If I could I would definitely use of GnuPG. Well, I have to bother.